# ReactJS material-UI tableData to parse nested JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, html-table, nested, material-ui

My client is ReactJS and server is Java Jersey based.

Java Jersey produces the following nested JSON.

```
[
    {
        "projectname": "BMI",
        "testRun": "5934391890034305",
        "numberOfTestcases": "3",
        "timeNowString": "Mon Sep 21 21:17:34 IST 2020",
        "oidobjList": [
            {
                "oid": "5f68cb16f01c7607230d1fcd"
            },
            {
                "oid": "5f68cb16f01c7607230d1fcf"
            },
            {
                "oid": "5f68cb16f01c7607230d1fd1"
            }
        ],
        "fileNameObjList": [
            {
                "fileName": "Basispath_BMI_0_out.gif"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "Basispath_BMI_1_out.gif"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "Basispath_BMI_2_out.gif"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectname": "BMI",
        "testRun": "3320691551029718",
        "numberOfTestcases": "3",
        "timeNowString": "Mon Sep 21 18:37:54 IST 2020",
        "oidobjList": [
            {
                "oid": "5f68a5aaf01ca8f40b42a4e7"
            },
            {
                "oid": "5f68a5aaf01ca8f40b42a4e9"
            },
            {
                "oid": "5f68a5aaf01ca8f40b42a4eb"
            }
        ],
        "fileNameObjList": [
            {
                "fileName": "Basispath_BMI_0_out.gif"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "Basispath_BMI_1_out.gif"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "Basispath_BMI_2_out.gif"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My ReactJS code is as follows:

```
{this.props.articles.map((el, index) => (                                 
    <Table
        tableHeaderColor="primary"
        tableHead={["Parameter", "Value"]}
        tableData={[                                            
            ["Project Name: ", el.projectname],
            ["Test Run: ", el.testRun],                                            
            ["No Of TestCases: ", el.numberOfTestcases],
            // ["File Name: ", el.fileNameObjList],
            ["Time Stamp: ", el.timeNowString],                                   
        ]}
    />
))}
```

The response received in client side is attached in the image

[image: Response received in client side]

Questions:

1. How to render nested JSON elements in ReactJS material-ui based tableData?
2. How to get filenames using map and index?
3. Please provide solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1 - First you need to decide how you will render your table. If you just want to render a single table for all your nested arrays, you can generate a single array of it and render normally. You can also render multipla tables, one for each nested array, it's your choice as a programmer.

2 - You can get filenames field by doing an simple map in `fileNameObjList`. But if you want a single array of filenames, you can either use `Array.reduce` or combine the mapped arrays with Array.concat or by pushing every item with an for loop

and also, I'm not sure but i don't think Material UI table is used that way. You may be using another data-table component that uses MUI